# Ubuntu 20.04 is consuming more battery

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery

My battery backup is 4 hours when I am using Windows But at the time of using Ubuntu20.04, it decreases to 2.5 hours. Is there any way by which we can reduce the power consumption when we are using Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Have you installed `tlp`?

Comment: Not yet, Should i try it? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I observed laptop fan was spinning high frequently while in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and consequently my laptop's battery backup was reduced (compared to running on 18.04 LTS)

Two ways to improve battery life:

1. use **powertop** utility with --auto-tune flag. You can also use it to investigate which hardware component in your system is using most power and when. Installation steps: https://linoxide.com/tools/install-use-powertop-ubuntu-16-04/
2. use my tiny little script: https://github.com/melvinga/cpuPowerProfilesForLinux
   It makes zero compromise on performance and my laptop battery backup improved from 5-6 hours to 8-10 hours.

Let me know if either of the above works for you.